# How to store a nested Associative Array with multiple values in a Cookie in Laravel 6 without converting it to String Data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-6

I want to store some Privacy and Email/Notification Settings Data in a Laravel Cookie for a Content Management System(CMS). By default Laravel Encrypts the Data, the Cookie exists in Web browser. I want to store all the settings boolean data in a single Associative Array and pass it to a Cookie with one Form POST. However, when I use the cookie() method, the Parameter 2 always asks for a string, Array/Object is rejected. I converted it to string with json_encode() and decrypted with json_decode() but I cannot get the default Framework Encrypted value. How can I solve this problem?

Things I have tried so far:

1. `json_encode()` the Assoc. Array and `json_decode()` the Encrypted Value (with the Default Laravel Encryption in place). The Default `Laravel` Framework returns null. `$_COOKIE[]` PHP Global returns the Encrypted value, not the real one.
2. I want the Default `Laravel` Encryption, so I don't wanna disable it in `EncryptCookies` Middleware. I want the `Cookie` to `Persist in a Separate Session and display value with Another Request` so that the Checkbox ticks in the Settings is Permanent as long as the User is Authenticated, but I failed to Do it.
3. Used `GuzzleHttp` Client as a 3rd Party. Same issue as `#1`.

Some Code Snippets for Assisstance:

1. Initializing the Array:

```
            'user_identity'     => Auth::user()->id,
            'name'              => Auth::user()->name,
            'subject'           => 'emails-notifications',
            'content'           => array()
        );
```

2. Initializing the Nested Content/Array:

```
$content                = array(
            'new_answer'                => false,
            'messages'                  => false,
            'comments'                  => false,
            'new_followers'             => false,
            'upvotes'                   => false,
            'shares'                    => false,
            'ask_SK'                    => false,
            'once_weekly'               => false,
            'once_day'                  => false,
            'popular_answers_shares'    => false,
            'popular_answers'           => false,
            'popular_shares'            => false
        );
```

3. Storing Content in a Cookie:

```
        $cookieName         = $cookies['name'];
        $cookies['content'] = $encryptedContent;
        $encryptedCookie    = json_encode($cookies);
        $cookie             = $this->setCookie($cookieName,$encryptedContent,$minutes);//setCookie Method has the cookie() global helper
```

4. Send Back Cookie with Response:

```
return back()->withCookie($cookie);
```

So my issue, in a nutshell is: How can I store a Nested Associative Array in a Cookie using ONLY default Laravel 6 Encryption/Decryption (and not json_encode()-ing + json_decode()-ing, as the Parameter 2 in cookie() global is forcing me to Do that)? Is there a better way to handle this issue?

Comment: Do you realize that `json_encode()` is not encrypting anything, but only encoding it to JSON?

Comment: The Cookie Data exists in the Browser. However, I can't use it in a Different Session with a Different Request-Responce cycle. That's why I'm confused. Is it because of Laravel Framework itself?